# javafx8 scenebuilder menu shows controls labeled for container object

Tags: javafx-8, scenebuilder

When I place JavaFX object inside a container, for example some checkboxes inside an hbox:

[image]

The scenebuilder controls for **each** checkbox show the container object in the menu (and different settings are shown here depending on the actual container):

[image]

But changing the "margin" value here, for example, clearly affects the individual checkbox and not the HBox. For example, setting only the middle checkbox to have a left margin of 20 yields a change to only the middle checkbox:

[image]

So why is that menu area labeled with the container name? I fear I am missing some fundamental design aspect by not understanding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are properties of the control that are specifically available when its parent is an `HBox`. They correspond to the static methods `HBox.setXXX(node, value)`, e.g. [`HBox.setHgrow(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#setHgrow-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.layout.Priority-).

If you put the check box in an `AnchorPane` instead, for example, you would see "Anchor Pane Constraints" instead of "HBox Constraints" and you would have options including "TopAnchor", "LeftAnchor" etc., corresponding to the static [`AnchorPane.setXXX(node, value)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html#setBottomAnchor-javafx.scene.Node-java.lang.Double-) methods.